# Force HTTP in an API callback method to avoid "The web page is not available" error in Rails 3.2 staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ssl, https

I have a callback method which is the callback URL after logging in via Salesforce.

Salesforce is redirecting properly back to my app in development but in staging, it's not reading/recognizing `https` protocols anymore.

One thing is that, `http` callback URLs are not allowed in Salesforce connect APP configuration, so I specified it to be `https`.

But the thing also is that, my app is not suitable for `https` protocol

Snippet of the callback URL:

```
https://staging.test.com/callback/salesforce?code=ABCDE
```

The browser keeps saying: `This webpage is not available`

If I manually change it in the address bar to `http://staging.test.com/callback/salesforce?code=ABCDE`

It will be redirected to my app without any problem(s). Of course, I don't want users to manually change the protocol to `http` just to login via Saleforce.

I've tried, to use https://github.com/bartt/ssl_requirement to enforce `HTTP` but no luck. It just says the `redirect_uri` is not matched to the callback URL specified in the configuration (because the one from the config is in `https`).

I've tried also to use a `before_filter` in `application_controller.rb` but it didn't work also.

```
before_filter :forcehttp

def forcehttp

  if request.ssl? && Rails.env.staging?
    redirect_to :protocol => 'http://', :status => :moved_permanently
  end
end
```

Any workarounds will be appreciated.